How do I display filtered results on UI using MVC?
I created a dropdown so that the user can filter the data by id_sucursal by using AJAX. I have succeeded in fetching the filtered results, but they are not being displayed on the UI after selecting!
This is the function I used so that when I select an option, the data is filtered and retrieved:
function filtrarPorSucursal() {
    var selectedSucursal = document.getElementById("sucursal").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "vistas/modulos/filtrar-sucursal.php?sucursal=" + selectedSucursal, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log("response from server:", xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                console.error("ERROR:", xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

This is what filtrar-sucursal.php looks like:
<?php
include("../../modelo/modelo.php");

// Retrieve the selected sucursal value from the request
$sucursal = $_GET['sucursal'];

// Use the sucursal value in your Modelo class to filter the orders
$respuesta = Modelo::listadoAtendidasPorSucursalModelo($sucursal);

// Return the filtered orders as JSON data
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>

I want the results to get sent to this method, but they don't seem to be because the interface doesn't change at all.
static public function listadoAtendidasControlador($sucursal = null)
    {
        if ($sucursal !== null) {
            $respuesta = Modelo::listadoAtendidasPorSucursalModelo("orden_servicio", $sucursal);
        } else {
            $respuesta = Modelo::listadoAtendidasModelo("orden_servicio");
        }
    
        foreach($respuesta as $valores) {
            ?>
            <div class="orden fancy-border" draggable="true" id="<?php echo $valores['id']; ?>">
                <div class="serie-folio">
                    <p class="num-orden">Num. orden: <?php echo $valores['serie'] . $valores['folio']; ?></p>
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?></p>
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i> <?php echo $valores['modelo']; ?></p>
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-user"></i> <?php echo $valores['id_vendedor']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

And this is what the console outputs
I'm getting the correct data, but the UI isn't changing. How do I display it?

the UI isn't changing...because you haven't written any JS code to make it change. Ajax calls don't automatically update the page. The result of the ajax request is returned to the javascript code in a variable. After that it's up to you to write some code to make the next thing happen

@ADyson thanks for the response. This is my first time using MVC and AJAX. I'm guessing I have to make another JS function that displays the filtered data, with HTML tags and everything. Would that defeat the purpose of the listadoAtendidasControlador method?

If you only ever do the filtering via ajax then yes, it would make sense to write a javascript equivalent of that function

@ADyson you were right, just slaved a few more hours away learning AJAX and I just made a function that works. Thanks for the help!
